# Can you maintain a grapple while on a moving mount?

Tags: dnd-5e, grapple, mount, forced-movement

You are mounted and you are currently grappling an opponent. Can you maintain the grapple on the opponent, and thus dragging him with you, when your mount is moving?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### No, you can not.

The [grappling](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Grappling) rules state that you can move a target you are grappling:

> ***Moving a Grappled Creature.*** When you move, you can drag or carry the grappled creature with you, but your speed is halved, unless the creature is two or more sizes smaller than you.

But, this applies only to you and your movement.

In D&D 5e, your movement is completely separate from the mount's movement. It even has its own turn distinct from yours; you can only control where it moves. Per the rules on [controlling a mount](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#ControllingaMount):

> The initiative of a controlled mount changes to match yours when you mount it. It moves as you direct it, and it has only three action options: Dash, Disengage, and Dodge.

Thus, the mount's movement will not allow you to move the grappled creature, and counts as an effect that removes the [grappled](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Grappled) creature from your reach:

> The condition also ends if an effect removes the grappled creature from the reach of the grappler or grappling effect, such as when a creature is hurled away by the *thunderwave* spell.

Answer (score 0):

## Yes, you can maintain a grapple while on a moving mount.

I have seen countless movies where actual people lean down from a horse, grab someone on the ground, and haul them onto their horse. Yes, they are cooperative stunt riders, I know, but the point is that it is possible to lean from a saddle and make a grapple attempt.

If a flying character grappled someone, they could use their move to lift the grappled creature off the ground and up and away. So why can't a mounted char use half their move to lift the grappled creature off the ground? (As long as they have the required STR to maintain that then should be the same gig, and as long as the mount has the required STR to carry both rider and creature, then why not use half its move to ride away?)

This complies with the rules that the grappling character moves the grappled creature (1/2 move), and the mount then is only carrying a weight limit. Though as DM, I would personally force a 1/2 move on the mount for carrying an unwanted "guest".

Of course, there's nothing to stop the grappled creature killing the mount on its turn...

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. All answers must directly answer the question; rather than saying "disagree" (which implies you're disagreeing with the other answer), you should phrase the first line to address the question itself (e.g. "Yes, you can maintain a grapple while on a moving mount"). I've attempted to edit your answer accordingly; please make sure it matches your intent.

Comment: I don't see anything but opinion supporting your case.